# C language arrays and pointers

Tags: pointers

What is the difference between  the two codes:

```
Char *trip[]= {"ham",
"BUM",
"Tum",
};

Char trip[][]= {"ham",
"BUM",
"Tum",
};
```

Thank you for the answers

Comment: With `char *trip[]` you can do `trip[2]++` and with `char trip[][]` you can't.

Comment: Is this the only diffrence between the two codes????

Comment: `char *trip[]` correspond to an array of pointer to `char` and `char trip[][]` correspond to an array of constant pointer to `char`.  So, if you need to iterate on each string, with `char *trip[]` you could do `trip[2]++` but you would loose the reference to the begining of the string.  And with `char trip[][]` to iterate on a string, you need to do it with a seperate variable of the type `char *`.